# recursive problem using the image module in racket

Tags: racket

I have the following error on line 27:

```
first: expects a non-empty list; given: #<image>
```

Is it a problem with recursion?

I've been researching but can't find an example where the image package is used recursively.

I can't think of anything, I don't understand why it gives me that error :(

```
; You must make a program that needs a list of n figures, which you will paint,
; all the color options that the user indicates and separates by a fixed distance that you determine.
; These figures contain a name (they depend on the naming options that you set),
; a measurement or measurements according to what the figure requires and an indicator of whether it is painted full or only the silhouette.
; NOTE: These drawings must be made using the image of the package.


(require 2htdp/image)

(define-struct triangulo_ (color size complete))
(define-struct cuadrado_  (color size complete))
(define-struct circulo_   (color size complete))

(define circulo   (make-circulo_   "yellow" 10 "outline"))
(define triangulo (make-triangulo_ "blue"   10 "solid"))
(define cuadrado  (make-cuadrado_  "orange" 10 "outline"))

(define lista_figuras (cons circulo (cons triangulo (cons cuadrado empty))))

(define (validar figura ID)
  (cond
    [(empty? figura) ID]
    [(and (circulo_? (first figura))   (positive? (circulo_-size (first figura))) (number? (circulo_-size (first figura)))   (string? (circulo_-color (first figura)))   (string? (circulo_-complete (first figura))))   (validar (rest figura) #t)]
    [(and (cuadrado_? (first figura))  (positive? (cuadrado_-size (first figura))) (number? (cuadrado_-size (first figura)))  (string? (cuadrado_-color (first figura)))  (string? (cuadrado_-complete (first figura))))  (validar (rest figura) #t)]
    [(and (triangulo_? (first figura)) (positive? (triangulo_-size (first figura))) (number? (triangulo_-size (first figura))) (string? (triangulo_-color (first figura))) (string? (triangulo_-complete (first figura)))) (validar (rest figura) #t)]
    [else (validar (rest figura) #f)]))

(define (pathway figura)
  (cond
    [(empty? figura) empty]
    [(circulo_?   (first figura)) (pathway(circle   (circulo_-size (first figura))   (circulo_-complete (first figura))   (circulo_-color (first figura))))]
    [(triangulo_? (first figura)) (pathway(triangle (triangulo_-size (first figura)) (triangulo_-complete (first figura)) (triangulo_-color (first figura))))]
    [(cuadrado_?  (first figura)) (pathway(square   (cuadrado_-size (first figura))  (cuadrado_-complete (first figura))  (cuadrado_-color (first figura))))]
    [else (pathway (rest figura))]))

(define (main figura)
  (cond
    [(boolean=? (validar figura 0) #t) (pathway figura)]
    [else "Error, solo se permiten: [ circulos, cuadrados y triangulos <equilateros> ]"]))

(main lista_figuras)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a type error. In the recursive call to `pathway`, you're passing in an image but it requires a list which contains triangulo_/cuadrado_/circulo_. Also the right hand side of the cond clauses in `validar` have multiple expressions, each will be evaluated from left to right but their values wouldn't matter, even if they're `false`. It's better to combine validation of each field with an `and`.

First, give a name to the structs you define, let's call it `ImageConfig`

At a higher level, the problem with the design is that you're mixing up list-processing with the processing of the element in the list. It's better to separate those.

Now separate the processing of `[List-of ImageConfig]` from `ImageConfig` for both `validar` and `pathway`.

```
; validar-l : [List-of ImageConfig] -> Boolean
; validar   : ImageConfig -> Boolean
; pathway-l : [List-of ImageConfig] -> [List-of Image]
; pathway   : ImageConfig -> Image
; main      : [List-of ImageConfig] -> [List-of Image]
```

---

```
; You must make a program that needs a list of n figures, which you will paint,
; all the color options that the user indicates and separates by a fixed distance that you determine.
; These figures contain a name (they depend on the naming options that you set),
; a measurement or measurements according to what the figure requires and an indicator of whether it is painted full or only the silhouette.
; NOTE: These drawings must be made using the image of the package.


(require 2htdp/image)

; ImageConfig is one of
(define-struct triangulo_ (color size complete))
(define-struct cuadrado_  (color size complete))
(define-struct circulo_   (color size complete))

(define circulo   (make-circulo_   "yellow" 10 "outline"))
(define triangulo (make-triangulo_ "blue"   10 "solid"))
(define cuadrado  (make-cuadrado_  "orange" 10 "outline"))

(define lista_figuras (cons circulo (cons triangulo (cons cuadrado empty))))

; [List-of ImageConfig] -> Boolean
(define (validar-l fl)
  (cond [(empty? fl) true]
        [else (and (validar (first fl)) (validar-l (rest fl)))]))

; ImageConfig -> Boolean
(define (validar f)
  (cond
    [(circulo_? f)   (and (positive? (circulo_-size f))   (number? (circulo_-size f))   (string? (circulo_-color f)))]
    [(cuadrado_? f)  (and (positive? (cuadrado_-size f))  (number? (cuadrado_-size f))  (string? (cuadrado_-color f)))]
    [(triangulo_? f) (and (positive? (triangulo_-size f)) (number? (triangulo_-size f)) (string? (triangulo_-color f)))]))


; ImageConfig -> Image
(define (pathway f)
  (cond
    [(circulo_?   f) (circle   (circulo_-size f)   (circulo_-complete f)   (circulo_-color f))]
    [(triangulo_? f) (triangle (triangulo_-size f) (triangulo_-complete f) (triangulo_-color f))]
    [(cuadrado_?  f) (square   (cuadrado_-size f)  (cuadrado_-complete f)  (cuadrado_-color f))]))

; [List-of ImageConfig] -> [List-of Image]
(define (pathway-l fl)
  (cond
    [(empty? fl) empty]
    [else (cons (pathway (first fl)) (pathway-l (rest fl)))]))

; [List-of ImageConfig] -> [List-of Image]
(define (main fl)
  (cond
    [(boolean=? (validar-l fl) true) (pathway-l fl)]
    [else (error "Error, solo se permiten: [ circulos, cuadrados y triangulos <equilateros> ]")]))

(main lista_figuras)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's what I needed. One last question, the only way to display multiple shapes is with a list? Or is there a way to display them without using a list?

Comment: Because I must show each figure separately with a distance that I consider, that is in the problem statement "and separates by a fixed distance that you determine." Do you see this possible?

Comment: Just traverse through a list of image, and use the `beside` library function to combine them. To add some space between images, you can add a white/transparent image of whatever length you want in the middle of the first and the recursive call within the `beside`.